# Include ID variable in imputed data frame

Tags: r, missing-data, r-mice

I'm using `library(mice)` to impute missing data. I want a way to tell `mice` that the ID variables should be included on the imputed data set but not used for the imputations.

For instance

```
#making a silly data frame with missing data
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
library(mice)

d1 <- data.frame(
  id = str_c(
    letters[1:20] %>% 
      rep(each = 5),
    1:5 %>% 
      rep(times  = 20)
    ),
  v1 = runif(100),
  v2 = runif(100),
  v3 = runif(100)
  )

d1[, -1] %<>%
  map(
    function(i){

      i[extract(sample(1:100, 5, F))] <- NA

      i
      }
    )
```

This is the returned `mids` object

```
m1 <- d1 %>% 
  select(-id) %>% 
  mice
```

How can I include `d1$id` as a variable in in each of the imputed data frames?

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways. First, simply append `id` to the imputed datasets

```
d2 <- complete(m1,'long', include = T) # imputed datasets in long format (including the original)
d3 <- cbind(d1$id,d2) # as datasets are ordered simply cbind `id`
m2 <- as.mids(d3) # and transform back to mids object
```

This ensures that `id` has no role in the imputation process, but is a bit sloppy and prone to error. Another way is to simply remove it from the predictor matrix.

The 2011 [manual](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v045i03) by Van Buuren & Groothuis-Oudshoorn says: "*The user can specify a custom predictorMatrix, thereby effectively regulating the number of predictors per variable. For example, suppose that bmi is considered irrelevant as a predictor. Setting all entries within the bmi column to zero effectively removes it from the predictor set ... will not use bmi as a predictor, but still impute it.*"

To do this

```
ini <- mice(d1,maxit=0) # dry run without iterations to get the predictor matrix

pred1 <- ini$predictorMatrix # this is your predictor matrix
pred1[,'id'] <- 0 # set all id column values to zero to exclude it as a predictor

m1 <-mice(d1, pred = pred1) # use the new matrix in mice
```

You can also prevent mice from imputing the variable, but as it contains no missing values this is not necessary (mice will skip it automatically).